# I'm not sure how to find a correlating generic type by naming convention

Tags: c#, regex, generics

My class structure is as follows:

- `Company.BusinessObjects.Order.OrderInformation`
- `Company.BusinessObjects.Order.TransactionInformation`
- `Company.BusinessObjects.Purchase.PurchaseInformation`
- ...
- `Company.MappingObjects.Order.OrderInformation`
- `Company.MappingObjects.Order.TransactionInformation`
- `Company.MappingObjects.Purchase.PurchaseInformation`
- ...

Additionally, I have specialized classes that I want to discover through naming convention:

- `Company.BusinessObjects.Order.X.ExtOrderInformation`
- `Company.BusinessObjects.Order.X.ExtTransactionInformation`
- `Company.BusinessObjects.Purchase.X.ExtPurchaseInformation`

I was originally using Regex to discover the matching `X`/`Ext` types:

```
    private Regex ExtRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Namespace>.*)\.(?<Type>.*)");
    private string RegexNamespace = @"Namespace";
    private string RegexType = @"Type";

    private static Type GetExtType(Type type)
    {
        var match = ExtRegex.Match(type.FullName);

        var xnamespace = match.Groups[RegexNamespace];
        var xtype = match.Groups[RegexType];

        var name = String.Format(@"{0}.X.Ext{1}", xnamespace, xtype);

        return ExtAssembly.GetType(name);
    }
```

However, this does not seem to work when I run into any type of generic type:

- `Company.BusinessObjects.BusinessObjectBase<T>`
- `Company.BusinessObjects.X.ExtBusinessObjectBase<T>`

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but I really would love to have a way of mapping my standard types to my `X`/`Ext` types including generic types.

Comment: It would be great if you provided exact necessary output for your input.

Comment: Why don't you use proper reflection APIs? Like `type.Namespace` and `type.Name`? You don't need regex to get this information.

Comment: Why would you want to find those based on a naming convention? If `ExtXXX` inherits from `XXX`, just find the classes that inherit from `XXX`, easy. If not, use an attribute to pair the two together. Or an interface, or ...

Comment: they don't inherit, they are related only by naming convention. And they are auto-generated, so I can't change that.